# Proving that the inverse of an inverse of an element $a$ equals the element $a$ in $G$

Tags: group-theory

In a group, prove that $\left ( a^{-1} \right )^{-1}=a$ for all $a\in G$

Since G is a group, there exists an $a^{-1} \in G$ so that $(aa^{-1})=(a^{-1}a)=e$

I would appreciate a hint to go further.

Comment: You probably want a hint to prove the equality $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$. Essential is that inverses are unique. The LHS is by definition the inverse of $a^{-1}$, but also RHS $a$ serves as inverse of $a^{-1}$.

Comment: @drhab My text hasn't defined what the inverse of an inverse of an element is. But glad you made the clarification.

Comment: I see the light now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it correct you want to show that $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$ for all $a \in G$? If so, a hint would be to use the definition of an inverse element: $x^{-1} = y \Leftrightarrow x \cdot y = y \cdot x = e$.

It then takes one line to realise that $(a^{-1})^{-1} =a$ holds.